# Get 3d object boundaries

Tags: opengl, 3d, game-physics

How do applications figure out the boundaries (just a box) of a 3d object?

Here's an example
[image: example]

I need this info for collision detection.

Comment: well you just compute maximum and minimum x y and z for all points, and you build a box with those values, that's really basic

Comment: You mean iterate through all the object vertices?

Comment: yeah when you load the object at the beginning, or it could even be directly in the mesh file

Comment: Im using Assimp. I never encountered a file format that stored this kind of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can compute the minimum and maximum (bounding box) of a 3D object.

```
void BBox(GLpoint *p, int n_vert, GLpoint& p_max, GLpoint& p_min)
{
    p_min.x = p[0].x;
    p_min.y = p[0].y;
    p_min.z = p[0].z;

    p_max.x = p[0].x;
    p_max.y = p[0].y;
    p_max.z = p[0].z;

    for (int i=1; i<n_vert; i++)
    {
        p_min.x = MIN(p_min.x, p[i].x);
        p_min.y = MIN(p_min.y, p[i].y);
        p_min.z = MIN(p_min.z, p[i].z);

        p_max.x = MAX(p_max.x, p[i].x);
        p_max.y = MAX(p_max.y, p[i].y);
        p_max.z = MAX(p_max.z, p[i].z);
    }
}
```